# In search of a component or device that switches multiple lines based on input selection

Tags: arduino, switches, multiplexer, attiny

Okay so the foundation for my curiosity is that in dealing with Arduinos, I found they can be used to program the similar but smaller ATtiny chips.  This is the main hookup configuration that some of you may be familiar with if you've done this before.

[image]

My problem then is I want to create a shield that sits atop the arduino and has multiple sockets for ATtinys, and a selector switch that allows for choosing which ATtiny is being programmed to.

I actually did make a prototype, and here's what it looks like.

[image]

Not the easiest thing to solder!

[image]

So it just has a power switch and a simple single pole triple throw.  Now I figured the best way to do it was to connect all of them to ground, and let the SPTT choose between which was powered.  And in order to make the board as simple as possible, I connected the 4 data lines (3 green and 1 yellow in the picture) straight down and all 3 ATtiny's are connected in parallel to the data, regardless of if they are powered.

Of course this board fails though because I incorrectly assumed there would be no leakage through the ATtiny's data lines, and there is, so the other 2 that aren't being programmed weakly connect through the micro to their respective grounds.

Here's a schematic of it, just pretend it's a SPTT instead of SPDT.

[image]

Okay to the point.  Effectively what I want is a device that performs this function.
Would this be considered a mux?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to the actual question, therefore only a comment. It is probably enough to switch the \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$ pin. The programming protocol defines strict timing with regard to this signal and thus if that signal is not present then nothing happens. Best to tie unused controller's \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$ to ground so you can be sure all outputs will be in high impedance mode. Then you route the programmer's \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$ pin to the device you actually want to program.

Comment: 1. you tie all unused controller's \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$ to ground (use a resistor so it can be overriden by your switch), resulting in all pins going into high impedance mode. 2. tie the \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$ of the controller you want to program to the programmer's pin10 (in this case).

Comment: So in other words: 1) Put pulldowns on each ATtiny's reset pins to GND, and switch the yellow line from the programmer to each ATtiny? Does this mean I don't need to switch the supply?

Comment: I didn't try it, but I think that should work just fine. It's worth to try, you can't get a much simpler circuit.

Comment: You keep responding while I'm typing :O Okay thanks, I'll have to try this out.

Comment: Yes I have trouble making up my mind while writing ;o)

Comment: But in keeping with the question, I think it'd still be useful to know of a component that can switch multiple lines to multiple groups of outputs.

Comment: Sorry so do you mean you think I don't need to switch the Vcc's and can switch only the reset line?

Comment: Only reset line, yes. Hop into chat tomorrow (time for bed for me). http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering

Comment: Thanks for the help.  To anyone else reading, I am still looking for an answer of course to the original question as well if anyone knows of a component that can do what I laid out in the last schematic.

Comment: Yes, you want a demultiplexer, perhaps a CD4555. -1 for huge photos and arduino image that do not provide useful information.

Comment: Sorry, you want me to put microscopic photos next time? That's so you can see it in detail cause lots of people complain about photos being too small.  And yes the arduino image does provide useful information, it shows how the arduino is connected to the ATtiny, and it's there to give background about what I'm trying to do.  Anyone else who has also done this would recognize that image from the very popular tutorial at HLTMedia I believe most people use. Just can't please em all I suppose

Comment: And the CD4555 is a __1 of 4__ decoder.  So it only selects one output.  Read the question again please.  I need a device that switches multiple lines __as a group__.  I want choice A to switch lines 1 through 4 to outputs A1 through A4, choice B to switch them to B1 through B4, and so on.

Comment: The photographs are not needed dude. It took my slow country line 2 minutes to get these pictures on-screen and shall I say it again... thye are not helpful to the question nor in answering it.

Comment: Ok well I reduced the quality so the images are fairly small now so try it again. I still have to disagree with you on them being useful, however.  Anyways, like I said the CD4555 doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: While switching the reset is a good idea (and you could even do it in software by using a different digital pin for each tiny's reset), do these ATtiny's also operate on that board in addition to being programmed there?  If not, a zero insertion force (ZIF) socket may be more useful.

Comment: I've really been meaning to get one of those, but no they don't operate there.

Comment: Anyways, I think I came up with the solution.  A number of tri-state buffers with tied selector or 'enable' lines, 1 for each data line.  And a line of those buffers for each possible output group.  I'm sure this probably exists somewhere as some other known component but I'm just too amateur to know about it. It's a 4 set tri-state buffer selector.

http://i306.photobucket.com/albums/nn255/Krb686/tri-state-buffer-selector.png

Comment: Yes, that's a fairly literal answer to what you originally asked (assuming hi-Z is a desirable "off" condition which is plausible here), however it's probably nowhere near the best solution for what you are trying to accomplish.  Also remember that one signal goes in the other direction, from the ATtiny to the ATmega so you'd have to run that through the buffers the other way from the rest.

Comment: Wow I actually didn't know that.  It looks like that's the MISO line? Dam that makes this more difficult. Well I guess I could just switch 2 of the buffers around the other way. Any other reasons why it wouldn't be a good solution? I definitely think hi-Z is what I want for this, after all low-Z caused the error initially

Comment: You have the source code of the programmer, why not look into that and change the program in such a way that you can select the correct controller from one of the Arduino input pins? This could again work with the !RESET-line trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use three [4066](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MC74HC4066ANG/MC74HC4066ANGOS-ND/919242) analog switches, with the 4 inputs of each chip wired in common with the inputs of the other chips, and the four control lines of each chip tied together and connected to your rotary switch.

[image]

Although this requires three chips, they are in a 14-pin DIP package so they are easy to wire up, and each can be selected by a single input (no decode), lending itself to the rotary switch in your diagram.

I have used these same devices (in a SMD package) to switch the four active leads (VCC detect, PGEC, PGED and MCLR) of a PIC programmer, and it works just fine.

The chip has a typical Ron (resistance between the inputs and outputs) of 80 Ω, but that does not seem to affect the operation of the programmer.  There are some quad bilateral switches available with a lower Ron, but they are only available in SMT packages.

Comment: Very nice! This looks what I need. Would this be different from using tri-state buffers, though? I'm guessing tri-state buffers are a one-way only so I'd need to hook some of them up backwards for the communication from ATtiny to programmer.   Other than that, any difference? I'm sure this would be better if communications needed to be 2-way but I don't think it's necessary in this case.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the programming signals for the ATtiny chips, but I know for the PIC at least one of the signals (PGED, or data) is bidirectional since the programmer needs to both write and read from the chip.  So you are better off using a chip like the 4066.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  Now if only they made an IC that had multiples of the 4066's with control bits internally tied, so I could get away with a single IC with ~24 ish pins!

Comment: Hey whaddya know, it looks like they just might!  Here's an IC that is essentially 2 4066's combined, in a 16-pin DIP package

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/MC14551B-D-96744.pdf

Comment: @krb686 The problem with this approach is you can't turn both the outputs off; one output is active with an input of 0, and the other one with an input of 1.

Comment: True, but I can't see why I would need to. It'd be the exact same with a physical multiple throw switch. I mean if its on and connected to an empty DIP socket it won't matter much. And there will be a master on/off switch as well for 5V going to all the sockets

Comment: @krb686 I agree, if it's connected to an empty socket it wouldn't matter.  But is it worth it to add that restriction to your circuit just to save one 14-pin DIP IC?

Comment: @tcrosley - none of the signals are bidirectional.  It's basically derived from SPI with the reset approximating the chip select (though perhaps not quite so simply)   Given what we've seen of the project so far, I'd say an "extra" 14-pin chip would be a rather substantial overhead.

Comment: @ChrisStratton they are not bidirectional, but all four lines are not the same direction.

Comment: @tcrosley I understand where you're coming from, why limit the circuit? But the way I'm looking at it is "Why use a lot more board space for functionality I will never need?" The circuit only has 1 function and it will never need to turn all of them off.  Say for instance I want to make a shield that can handle 4 chips.   4x14 pins =  56 pins worth of board space. If they make a 4 channel IC like the one I linked, it could be done in 24 pins (vcc, gnd, 2 ctrl bits, 16 data lines, and 4 common data lines).   I want this thing to fit into the same form factor as my prototype.

Comment: Since this is what I'll probably go with, I'll accept as the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a analog bus switch or multiplexer. Analog meaning it's not digitally controlled (serial/i2c/spi). A 4 bit (or quad) 3 to 1 (or higher, 4 to 1, 5 to 1, 5 to 2, etc) switch would be best, as it would be an all in one solution for your 4 wire, 3 IC setup.

An ever so slightly more complex, if not cheaper and easier solution to implement because they are easier to find, would be to use two 2:1 multiplexers/switches. The Switched side of one will lead to either an Attiny, or to the second bus switch, which leads to the other two Attinys. Below is a representative schematic. Any 4 bit 2:1 multiplexer will do.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f38Xql.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Still can't seem to find a component that satisfies this requirement.  I've searched for bus switches and multiplexers, and the best I've found matches what I linked in the comments on tcrosley's answer, an IC that can switch 4 lines to 2 separate groups of 4 outputs.  I've yet to see any component that can switch to more than 2 output groups.

Comment: Well I did just find this.  It switches 4 sets of 4 data line inputs all to a single 4-set output.  What I want is the exact opposite. I guess I need a quad 1:4 mux

http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/sites/default/files/ees/files/NI/pdfs/01/02/DS010226.pdf

Comment: @krb686 remember, the miso line is the reverse direction of the other three lines. And I think you are too hung up on wanting a single chip. 4:1 bus switches are often set up as three cascading 2:1 bus switches.